# Comparing DOB to date today

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

[image]

I am trying to check the age so I can display a note if the clients are under 23 any idea on how to do so? I am using code first entity framework.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty straight-forward:

```
var under23 = DateTime.Today.AddYears(-23);
var clients = db.Clients.Where(m => m.ClientDOB > under23);
```

Essentially, you're just subtracting 23 years from the current date and then querying for clients where DOB is greater than that, i.e. they were born on a date greater than 23 years ago, making them less than 23 years old.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the logic you may use

```
    DateTime date=DateTime.Now;
    var expectedMinDate=date.AddYears(-23);
    DateTime clientBirthDate=Convert.ToDateTime("23/08/1993");
    if(clientBirthDate>expectedMinDate)
    {
    Console.Write("Smaller than 23");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.Write("Greater than or equal to 23");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    DateTime birthday = new DateTime(1995, 7, 30);
    var age = GetAge(birthday);

    if (age < 23)
    {
         // do something
    }

    public int GetAge(DateTime dob)
    {
        var today = DateTime.Today;
        var age = today.Year - dob.Year;
        if (dob > today.AddYears(-age))
            age--;

        return age;
    }
```